# Multiple Models in a View in ASP.NET MVC Entity FrameWork

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I want two **CheckBoxList** an index view, those
**CheckBoxList** dynamically bind from two different tables. One is **Sports**
and another is **Country**.

Basically i try through **EditorTemplates**, but it not working with two
models. i face problem to use two model in a single view.

**This is my Index Method in Controller**

```
    SampleDBContext db = new SampleDBContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Sports"] = db.Sports.ToList();
        ViewData["Country"] = db.Countries.ToList();             
        return View(ViewData["Sports"]);// I am confused and i don't know what to write there we can call both table data.
    }
```

**Template View for Sports**

```
@model MVCDEMO.Models.Sports

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.s_Id)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => (bool)x.is_selected)
@Html.DisplayFor( x => x.s_Name)
```

**Template View for Country**

```
@model MVCDEMO.Models.Country

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.c_Id)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => (bool)x.is_selected)
@Html.DisplayFor( x => x.c_Name)
```

**Index View**

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            Select Sports
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.EditorForModel()//what to write it recognize Sports template
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            Select Country
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.EditorForModel()//what to write it recognize Country template
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If i work for single Model it work perfectly.

Comment: [Multiple Models in a View in ASP.NET MVC 4 / MVC 5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC)

Comment: thanks, without @html.EditorForModel() i solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I would personaly use a strongly typed view model having `Sports` and `Countries` as properties, instead of using ViewData:

```
public class IndexPageViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Sports> Sports { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Country> Countries { get; set; }        
}
```

Creating two partial views, one for each class (`Sport` and `Country`), would allow you to use the `@Html.EditorForModel()` helper. Reusing the partial views would also be an added benefit, but this obviously depends on the specific application.

Please note that the 'EditorForModel' helper will render an editor for each property of the model. If you need to have a different kind of editor, for example a dropdown menu, I'm not sure `EditorForModel` should be used.

Comment: if i use @model IEnumerable<CHBox.Models.PageNameViewModel> in view than how i target specific model for @html.EditorForModel().
I try but i fail...

Comment: You should use `@model IndexPageViewModel` in view and `@model Sport` in partial view.

Comment: IndexPageViewModel is just a name I've made up for the view model to contain the two lists, you may rename it if you like.